# Display the Recipes that i added to matrix

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]This form to create a recipe with storage by LOCAL STORAGE.
In the store file, I display a set of recipes with their presentation on the interface within the "state" matrix, but when I add a recipe I want to display it in the recipes matrix "state".
The problem is that the recipe is stored by localStorage, but not added to the recipe matrix "state".
And in the picture, the recipe matrix is displayed
How can I solve the problem?

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import image1 from '../assets/img/image4.jpg'
import image2 from '../assets/img/image2.jpg'
import image3 from '../assets/img/image3.jpg'
import image4 from '../assets/img/insta2.jpg'
Vue.use(Vuex)
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        loadedRecipes:[
            {imageUrl:image3,
                id:'3' , title:'Homemade Burger',
                description:'Small plates, salads & sandwiches - an intimate setting with 12 indoor 
             seats plus patio seating..',
                ingredients: '25 Eges 30kg Water'
            },
            {imageUrl:image1,
                id:'1' , title:'Cake',
                description:'Small plates, salads & sandwiches - an intimate setting with 12 indoor 
                seats plus patio seating..',
                ingredients: '25 Eges 30kg Water'
            },
            {imageUrl:image4,
                id:'4' , title:'Salad',
                description:'Small plates, salads & sandwiches - an intimate setting with 12 indoor 
              seats plus patio seating..',
                ingredients: '25 Eges 30kg Water'
            },
            {imageUrl:image2,id:'2' ,
             title:'Kabseh',description:'Small plates, salads & sandwiches - an intimate setting with 
            12 indoor seats plus patio seating.',
             ingredients: '25 Eges 30kg Water'
            }
    
          ],
          user:{
              id:'nvdcjavdah',
              registeredRecipes:['jhvjhvmnbvhj']
          }
    },
    mutations:{
        // createRecipe(state,payload){
        //     state.loadedRecipes.push(payload)
        // }
    },
    actions:{
        // createRecipe(payload){
        //     const recipe = {
        //         title : payload.title,
        //         imageUrl: payload.imageUrl,
        //         description:payload.description,
        //         ingredients:payload.ingredients,
        //         date:payload.date,
        //         id:'hgxckjh'
        //     }
        //     console.log(recipe)
        // }
    },
    getters:{
        loadedRecipes(state){
            return state.loadedRecipes.sort((RecipeA,RecipeB)=>{
                return RecipeA.id >RecipeB.id
            })
        },
        featuredRecipes(state,getters){
            return getters.loadedRecipes.slice(0,5)
        },
        loadedRecipe(state){
            return (recipeId)=>{
                return state.loadedRecipes.find((recipe)=>{
                    return recipe.id === recipeId
                })
            }
        },
        addANewRecipe(state,newRecipe){         
                return state.loadedRecipes.push(newRecipe)            
        }
    }
})
```

CreateRecipe.vue:
This form to create a recipe with storage by LOCAL STORAGE:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
          <h2 class="btn-style">Create Recipe</h2>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <form @submit.prevent="onCreateRecipe">
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="title"
                  label="Title"
                  id="title"
                  v-model="title"
                  color="#43A047"
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="imageUrl"
                  label="ImageUrl"
                  id="imageUrl"
                  v-model="imageUrl"
                  color="#43A047"
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <img :src="imageUrl" height="300px" />
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="description"
                  label="Description"
                  id="description"
                  v-model="description"
                  color="#43A047"
                  multi-line
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="ingredients"
                  label="Ingredients"
                  id="ingredients"
                  v-model="ingredients"
                  color="#43A047"
                  multi-line
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-btn
                  class="green darken-1 color"
                  :disabled="!formIsValid"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  Create Redcipe
                </v-btn>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </form>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      description: "",
      ingredients: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formIsValid() {
      return (
        this.title !== "" &&
        this.description !== "" &&
        this.imageUrl !== "" &&
        this.ingredients != ""
      );
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onCreateRecipe() {
      if (!this.formIsValid) {
        return;
      }
      const recipeData = {
        title: this.title,
        description: this.description,
        imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
        ingredients: this.ingredients,
      };
      console.log(recipeData);
      const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(recipeData);
      console.log("S: ", stringifiedData);
      localStorage.setItem("recipe", stringifiedData);
      console.log("We got : ", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipe")));
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.btn-style {
  color: #43a047;
}
.color {
  color: #fafafa;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CreateRecipie.vue, You are writing data to localStorage but not to the Vuex store, and the store is not connected to the localStorage. If you write data to store then it should work properly.

### Some code which needs to be updated:

**Store:**

```
mutations:{
        createRecipe(state,payload){
            Vue.set(state, 'loadedRecipes', [...loadedRecipes, payload])
            state.loadedRecipes.push(payload)
        }
    },
```

**Create Receipe**

```
onCreateRecipe() {
  if (!this.formIsValid) {
    return;
  }
  const recipeData = {
    title: this.title,
    description: this.description,
    imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
    ingredients: this.ingredients,
  };
  this.$store.commit('createRecipe', recipeData)
}
```